# How do i make multiple checkbox with a unique id using WTForms so that i can store it in shelves?

Tags: python, select, flask, wtforms

How can I make multiple checkbox using WTForms and render it to my html page? 
This is what i've come up with using WTForms but i was told that by using Boolean(True,False) it will only applies to only  one checkbox instead of multiple checkbox.And how can i append the selected check-boxes into a dictionary with a unique ID given to it?

Im quite new to python,flask and WTForms. Thank you for taking your time to help me out. It is also fine to  give me some suggestions/guides to help me work on it.

[A preview of my HTML doctor booking page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhTmV.png)

```html
 

   {% extends 'layout.html' %}
    {% block body %}

 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/appointment.css">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container text-center">
          <div id="head">
       <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
              </div>

        <div id="head-p"> <p> Doctor Opening Hours Slot  </p> </div>

      </div>
    </div>



      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading"> <h3> Doctor Admin Page </h3> </div>
        <div id="appointment_box">


        </div>


        <form>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th> Monday  </th>
                    <td id="m1" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 8 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="m2" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 9 : 00</td>
                    <td id="m3" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 10 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="m4" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 11 : 00</td>
                    <td id="m5" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 12 : 00</td>
                    <td id="m6" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 13 : 00</td>
                    <td id="m7" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 14 : 00</td>
                    <td id="m8" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 15 : 00</td>
                    <td id="m9" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 16 : 00</td>
                    <td id="m10" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 17 : 00</td>
                    <td id="m12" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 18 : 00</td>
            </tr>

    <tr>
                      <th> Tuesday </th>
                    <td id="t1" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 8 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="t2" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 9 : 00</td>
                    <td id="t3" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 10 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="t4" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 11 : 00</td>
                    <td id="t5" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 12 : 00</td>
                    <td id="t6" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 13 : 00</td>
                    <td id="t7" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 14 : 00</td>
                    <td id="t8" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 15 : 00</td>
                    <td id="t9" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 16 : 00</td>
                    <td id="t10" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 17 : 00</td>
                    <td id="t11" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 18 : 00</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                              <th> Wednesday </th>
                    <td id="w1" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 8 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="w2" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 9 : 00</td>
                    <td id="w3" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 10 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="w4" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 11 : 00</td>
                    <td id="w5" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 12 : 00</td>
                    <td id="w6" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 13 : 00</td>
                    <td id="w7" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 14 : 00</td>
                    <td id="w8" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 15 : 00</td>
                    <td id="w9" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 16 : 00</td>
                    <td id="w10" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 17 : 00</td>
                    <td id="w11" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 18 : 00</td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
                              <th> Thursday </th>
                    <td id="th1" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 8 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="th2" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 9 : 00</td>
                    <td id="th3" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 10 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="th4" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 11 : 00</td>
                    <td id="th5" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 12 : 00</td>
                    <td id="th6" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 13 : 00</td>
                    <td id="th7" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 14 : 00</td>
                    <td id="th8" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 15 : 00</td>
                    <td id="th9" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 16 : 00</td>
                    <td id="th10" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 17 : 00</td>
                    <td id="th11" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 18 : 00</td>
            </tr>


                    <tr>
                              <th> Friday </th>
                    <td id="f1"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 8 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="f2"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 9 : 00</td>
                    <td id="f3"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 10 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="f4"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 11 : 00</td>
                    <td id="f5"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 12 : 00</td>
                    <td id="f6"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 13 : 00</td>
                    <td id="f7"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 14 : 00</td>
                    <td id="f8"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 15 : 00</td>
                    <td id="f9"  style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 16 : 00</td>
                    <td id="f10" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 17 : 00</td>
                    <td id="f11" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 18 : 00</td>
            </tr>

                    <tr>
                              <th> Saturday </th>
                    <td id="s1" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 8 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="s2" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 9 : 00</td>
                    <td id="s3" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 10 : 00 </td>
                    <td id="s4" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 11 : 00</td>
                    <td id="s5" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 12 : 00</td>
                    <td id="s6" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 13 : 00</td>
                    <td id="s7" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 14 : 00</td>
                    <td id="s8" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 15 : 00</td>
                    <td id="s9" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 16 : 00</td>
                    <td id="s10" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 17 : 00</td>
                    <td id="s11" style="background-color:lightgrey"> {{dform.active}} 18 : 00</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      <br>
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-11">


                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

        </div>
      </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

```html
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, session
import shelve
# <<<<<<< HEAD
from wtforms import Form, StringField, BooleanField,TextAreaField,RadioField, SelectField, validators, PasswordField, DateField, SubmitField, \
 IntegerField, FileField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from datetime import date
import uuid
from wtforms import widgets, SelectMultipleField

app = Flask(__name__)

#this is my form!
 class DoctorAppointment(Form):
   active = BooleanField(True, False)
   
   
@app.route("/doctorbooking")
def doctorbooking():
    doctor_form = DoctorAppointment(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        check_list = doctor_form.active.data
        doctorappointment = Timeslots(day,check_list)

        db_read = shelve.open("doctorappointment.db")

        try:
            doctorappointmentlist = db_read["doctorappointment"]

        except:
            doctorappointmentlist = {}

        doctorappointmentlist[day] = check_list.data


        db_read.close()


        flash("Appointment added sucessfully!")
        
          return render_template("DoctorBooking.html", title="Doctor Booking",dform = doctor_form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if it helps. In the end, a dictionary (data) is returned with the names of the checked checkboxes.

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/index/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    weekdays = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    timeslots = ['8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '13PM', '14PM','15PM','16PM','17PM','18PM']

    if request.method == "POST":
        data = dict((key, request.form.getlist(key) if len(
            request.form.getlist(key)) > 1 else request.form.getlist(key)[0])
            for key in request.form.keys())
        print (data) # do whatever you want with this data dict. Store it, flash messages, etc.

    return render_template('index.html',
       weekdays = weekdays,
       timeslots = timeslots,
       )
```

The template

```
<form method = "post" action = "">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      {% for weekday in weekdays %}
      <tr>
        <th> {{ weekday }} </th>
          {% for timeslot in timeslots %}
            <td><input id="{{ weekday+timeslot }}" type="checkbox" name="{{ weekday+timeslot }}">{{ timeslot }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </thead>
  </table>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yes it worked! how do i get the values that are not ticked as well?

Comment: and what does this part do:   data = dict((key, request.form.getlist(key) if len(
            request.form.getlist(key)) > 1 else request.form.getlist(key)[0])
            for key in request.form.keys())

Comment: Well, with the if statement it gets the values if more than 1 checkbox is checked, else it returns just the one. Checkboxes that are not checked do not return anything at all, so you cannot get any values of empty checkboxes. The data object simply contains the checked checkboxes in a dictionary.

Comment: Is there any way I can select all the check-boxes instead of selecting one by one?

Comment: What do you mean? Normally all checkboxes can be checked. Radio buttons (if name is identical) cannot. Are you saying your checkboxes behave like radio buttons? If yes, please post your html code here. There must be something going on there.

Comment: i mean by the default, the form all the checkboxes will be ticked, then if they don't want the checkbox to be tick, they can just unchecked it.

Comment: as it is quite time consuming to tick all instead of unticking the checkboxes that they are not in used.

Comment: I understand whay you are saying. You can just add the word 'checked' to the inputtype in your template but without both the ' to have them checked by default. I think if you uncheck them and press submit button all things go well, but lets find out,  just test it?

Comment: td><input id="{{ weekday + timeslot }}" class="input-helper" type=checked onchange ="isChecked()" name="{{ weekday + ':' + '' + timeslot }}">{{ timeslot }} </td>

Comment: is it like this?

Comment: Like this should also work for setting default: 
td><input id="{{ weekday + timeslot }}" class="input-helper" checked onchange ="isChecked()" name="{{ weekday + ':' + '' + timeslot }}">{{ timeslot }} </td>