# Problem retrieving checkbox button value in flask using bootstrap btn-group-toggle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I want to style my checkboxes to look like buttons using the bootstrap class `<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">`
but it does not let me retrieve checkbox values in Flask like it usually did when I did not use this bootstrap class.

I have created a page with dynamically generated checkboxes using the code below. I use the following Flask code to retrieve checkbox values `checkboxValues = request.form.getlist('checkbox')`. How can I retrieve these checkbox values whilst having it nicely styled as buttons?

```
<form action="start" method="post">
{% for text in slideText %}
  {% set count = namespace(a=0) %}
  {% set slideNumber = namespace(a=loop.index-1) %}
  <h2>Slide {{ loop.index }}</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  {% for innerText in text %}
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" autocomplete="off" value="{{ slideNumber.a }}.{{ count.a }}"> {{ innerText }}
    </label>
    {% set count.a = count.a + 1 %}
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
<br>
<input class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871445/how-do-i-make-multiple-checkbox-with-a-unique-id-using-wtforms-so-that-i-can-sto/53958213#53958213

Comment: I can alreadyretrieve unique checkbox values I just need to know how to do it with<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons"> styling as it doesn't let me retrieve the data when I use that